# Assignment within an expression

Tags: expression, system-verilog

There is a description on systemverilog LRM for “Assignment within an expression”
The example is

```
a = (b = (c = 5));
```

When I try to compile with this code, compiler shows an error of “expecting a right parenthesis”.
Is this feature currently supported by incisive and synthesizable?

Comment: Could you give us a bit more context? What is the surrounding code of this snippet?

Comment: cadance nc does not compile it, all others do. Cadance does not implement the standard here. Which one compiler did you use?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I am now using cadence incisive or xcellium version.

Answer (score 0):

This concept of "Assignment within an expression" works inside a procedural block .

Try out the below snippet of code to understand further.

```
module mm;
  logic [7:0] a,b,c;

  initial
    $monitor("a=%d,b=%d,c=%d",a,b,c);

  initial begin
    a = (b = (c = 5)+1);
    #10;
    a = (b = (c = 5)+1)-3;
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: As mentioned by Serge above, it looks like that it comes from compiler issue. I am now using cadence xcellium, it seems that doesn’t support “assignment within an expression”. I also tried with similar style as you left, it didn’t make it work.